# Gitlab-runner stops on "Initializing executor providers"

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

Gitlab-runner service can not start working. It stops on "Initializing executor providers".

Docker executor are used.

```bash
evoro@lin-ev:~$ sudo systemctl status gitlab-runner.service 
● gitlab-runner.service - GitLab Runner
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-05-18 18:18:51 +08; 9s ago
   Main PID: 60537 (gitlab-runner)
      Tasks: 10 (limit: 18943)
     Memory: 11.3M
        CPU: 54ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/gitlab-runner.service
             └─60537 /usr/bin/gitlab-runner run --working-directory /var/lib/gitlab-runner --config /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml --service gitlab-runner --user gitlab-runner

мая 18 18:18:51 lin-ev systemd[1]: Started GitLab Runner.
мая 18 18:18:51 lin-ev gitlab-runner[60537]: Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=60537 revision=436955cb version=15.11.0
мая 18 18:18:51 lin-ev gitlab-runner[60537]: Starting multi-runner from /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml...  builds=0
мая 18 18:18:51 lin-ev gitlab-runner[60537]: Running in system-mode.                           
мая 18 18:18:51 lin-ev gitlab-runner[60537]:                                                   
мая 18 18:18:51 lin-ev gitlab-runner[60537]: Configuration loaded                                builds=0
мая 18 18:18:51 lin-ev gitlab-runner[60537]: listen_address not defined, metrics & debug endpoints disabled  builds=0
мая 18 18:18:51 lin-ev gitlab-runner[60537]: [session_server].listen_address not defined, session endpoints disabled  builds=0
мая 18 18:18:51 lin-ev gitlab-runner[60537]: Initializing executor providers                     builds=0
evoro@lin-ev:~$ sudo gitlab-runner -v
Version:      15.11.0
Git revision: 436955cb
Git branch:   15-11-stable
GO version:   go1.19.6
Built:        2023-04-21T20:32:43+0000
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

The same behavior is on a last gitlab-runner version

The issue is still there

```
evoro@lin-ev:~$ sudo gitlab-runner -v
Version:      16.3.0
Git revision: 8ec04662
Git branch:   16-3-stable
GO version:   go1.20.5
Built:        2023-08-20T17:57:47+0000
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

evoro@lin-ev:~$ sudo apt show gitlab-runner 
Package: gitlab-runner
Version: 16.3.0
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Maintainer: GitLab Inc. <support@gitlab.com>
Installed-Size: 523 MB
Provides: gitlab-ci-multi-runner
Depends: git, curl, tar, ca-certificates
Suggests: docker-engine
Conflicts: gitlab-runner-beta, gitlab-ci-multi-runner, gitlab-ci-multi-runner-beta
Replaces: gitlab-ci-multi-runner
Homepage: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner
Download-Size: 480 MB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: https://packages.gitlab.com/runner/gitlab-runner/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
Description: GitLab Runner

evoro@lin-ev:~$ sudo systemctl status gitlab-runner.service 
● gitlab-runner.service - GitLab Runner
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-08-31 13:36:57 +08; 4min 23s ago
   Main PID: 32258 (gitlab-runner)
      Tasks: 11 (limit: 18927)
     Memory: 12.5M
        CPU: 87ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/gitlab-runner.service
             └─32258 /usr/bin/gitlab-runner run --working-directory /var/lib/gitlab-runner --config /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml --service gitlab-runner -->

авг 31 13:36:57 lin-ev systemd[1]: Started GitLab Runner.
авг 31 13:36:57 lin-ev gitlab-runner[32258]: Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=32258 revision=8ec04662 version=16.3>
авг 31 13:36:57 lin-ev gitlab-runner[32258]: Starting multi-runner from /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml...  builds=0 max_builds=0
авг 31 13:36:57 lin-ev gitlab-runner[32258]: Running in system-mode.                           
авг 31 13:36:57 lin-ev gitlab-runner[32258]:                                                   
авг 31 13:36:57 lin-ev gitlab-runner[32258]: Configuration loaded                                builds=0 max_builds=1
авг 31 13:36:57 lin-ev gitlab-runner[32258]: listen_address not defined, metrics & debug endpoints disabled  builds=0 max_builds=1
авг 31 13:36:57 lin-ev gitlab-runner[32258]: [session_server].listen_address not defined, session endpoints disabled  builds=0 max_builds=1
авг 31 13:36:57 lin-ev gitlab-runner[32258]: Initializing executor providers                     builds=0 max_builds=1
```

The questions is:

1. How to fully start a gitlab runner?
2. What is the reason of this gitlab-runner's issue?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the result of a bug they are still working on: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/36805

Also, check your version numbers - I ran into this when I upgraded my 16.1 runner to 16.5, but downgrading to match the server's 16.4 fixed it.